# How to make a J-Unit Test property file path dependent on environment?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit

I am setting up an Jenkins Environment.
Til now I was running all J-Unit tests only locally, therefore I had an Abstract Test-Class which sets up the properties path hard coded:

```
PropertyLoader.getSingleton().init("/my/path");
```

Of course the path is different on the build server. What is the best practice to pass a path by running the test?

Comment: Is the file available in `src/test/resources` ?

Comment: No, it's a path outside the Java project. It's a Folder where all properties are stored, could be "somewhere" on the Server. Therefore, an relative path doesn't work. I have to pass an absolute path.

Comment: You might even be able to use Junit's rule: `@Rule public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();`.

Comment: No, because it's a path where System Properties are stored. There are a lot of property files, they differ on the Server and on local dev Environment.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure your pom for different environment, then replace the property value according to the env you build.